# Magento 1.8.1 Issue to send Product email to friend despite other notifications works

Tags: magento-1.8, product, email, smtp

I am using Magento CE 1.8.1 version and I have installed Aschroder SMTP module and have an Amazon SMTP server and I’ve noticed that only email a friend [does not send mail and according to this site](http://www.mage-contacts.com/email-a-friend-does-not-send-mails-with-amazon-smtp/).

The problem is with the SMTP server. So I followed their instruction and modified `app/code/local/Mage/Sendfriend/Model/Sendfriend.php` for the `send()` function but it did not work:

```
public function send()
{
    if ($this->isExceedLimit()){
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper(‘sendfriend’)->__(‘You have exceeded limit of %d sends in an hour’, $this->getMaxSendsToFriend()));
    }

    /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
    $translate = Mage::getSingleton(‘core/translate’);
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
    $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel(‘core/email_template');

    $message = $message."Message sent by: ".$this->getSender()->getName()." ".$this->getSender()->getEmail();
    $sender = array(
        ‘name’ => Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/name'),
        ‘email’ => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')
    );
```

Thank you for any guidance that you can provide.

Comment: Any error message, exception, something in the log? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: Hello Fabian, I found the issue it was due to a third extension related to Wishlist (reason why I couldn't send emails)